# modify metada description from image

Tags: metadata, exif, exiftool

I want to change or modify the metadata of an image, such as the name shown, and you can add a description that would be perfect. The end, is to be able to automate the loading of images in wordpress and that this, take the values of the image

I installed exiftool, but I do not see how to change or add those tags.
If the image is called
**home.jpg**
that the title is
**Start of my presentation page**
instead of
**home**

Sorry to explain it wrong, if you need, I give a more extensive example

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague on the specifics, such as where you're trying to add the metadata (local system before upload?  file already on the WP system?).  But hopefully this info will be helpful.

WordPress seems to auto fill the Title from the `IPTC:Headline` tag and the Caption from the `IPTC:Caption-Abstract` tag.  Alternative Text and Description do not appear to be auto filled.

The exiftool command to set these values, assuming you're using the Windows exiftool executable, would be:
`exiftool -Caption-Abstract="My Caption" -Headline="My Title" file.jpg`

This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.